# suid binary privilege escalation

Tags: linux, elevated-privileges

if **/usr/bin/bash** has the suid bit set
why does my euid change to root only when I use the -p option like so `/usr/bin/bash -p`
what does this -p option stand for?
and when you spawn a bash shell from a suid binary why **euid** is set to **root** and why not **uid**?

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> `-p`
> Turn on privileged mode. In this mode, the $BASH_ENV and $ENV files are not processed, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, and the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored. If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, these actions are taken and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is supplied at startup, the effective user id is not reset. Turning this option off causes the effective user and group ids to be set to the real user and group ids.

This is done because setuid shell scripts have been a common source of security bugs. So the programmer is required to use the `-p` option to indicate that they really need the privilege escalation, e.g. by using

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -p
```

Without this, setting the `suid` bit on `/usr/bin/bash` itself would be an enormous security hole, since most scripts don't take the necessary precautions needed when running with elevated permissions.

Comment: suppose i spawn a bash shell using this -p option if I try the passwd command will the passwd of the user who spawned the shell get changed or the root user's passwd?

Comment: I think it will be root, but it depends on precisely how `passwd` chooses its default.